# Регрессия с Garch error

Tags: r

Добрый День! Необходимо в R прогнать линейную модель двухфакторную, но с GARCH ошибкой. В инете посёчил инфу, но особо ничего не нашел, как это сделать. В основном описаны GARCH-Arima модели временных рядов. Знаю, как прогонять обычную линейную модель lm(data=..., y~x), а кто нибудь знает, как сделать,чтобы Garch ошибка была? В обычной линейной модели ошибка по дефолту i.i.d, а необходимо, чтобы она задавалась через garch (1,1)

Comment: "чтобы Garch ошибка была?" - уточните вопрос.

Comment: В обычной линейной модели ошибка по дефолту i.i.d, а необходимо, чтобы она задавалась через garch (1,1)

Comment: Добавте в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/657455/edit). Комментарии не все читают.